# Why do concat and << change a string variable when assigning doesn't

Tags: ruby

If I have the following:

```
puts "---doesn't change---"

def change_string(val)
  val = "abc"
end

str = "some"
change_string(str)
puts str

puts "---does change---"

def change_string_two(val)
  puts "val is of class: #{val.class}"
  val << " extra"
  puts "val is of class: #{val.class}"
end

change_string_two(str)
puts str
puts "str is of type: #{str.class}"

puts "---does change---"

str = "xxx"

def change_string_three(val)
 val.concat(" more things")
end

change_string_three(str)
puts str
```

It ouptuts:

```
---doesn't change---
some
---does change---
val is of class: String
val is of class: String
some extra
str is of type: String
---does change---
xxx more things
```

I understand that it's passing an object reference but I'm confused as to how in one scenario it doesn't change and in two scenarios, it does change. Is this peculiar to strings in Ruby?

Comment: The same would happen with anything, e.g. arrays: `def foo(arr); arr << :yay; end; arr = []; foo(arr); arr #⇒ [:yay]`.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin I agree - that's my point. Arrays will have similar to pass-by-ref  semantics and strings have somewhat bizarre behavior. If the argument it that it just works that way, so be it; it just seems a bit odd hence the question

Comment: The title says _"string variable"_, but there's no such thing. Variables don't have a class, the objects they are referring to do. You can either change the string (e.g. have it append something to itself via `concat`) or change the variable (make it refer to another object via assignment). Mixing the two and thinking in terms of _"change a string variable"_ will just add to the confusion. Variables and objects are not the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not peculiar to Ruby. `val.concat("x")` and `val << "x"` modify the value `val` refers to. Whenever you have a function where the argument being passed is a reference, then methods called on the argument which mutate it will result in mutations on the originally referenced thing.

An assignment like `val = "abc"` on the other hand reassigns the local variable `val` to refer to something new, and leaves what it previously referred to untouched.

If you want to replace the string rather than add to it, use `val.replace("abc")`, e.g.

```
def replace(val)
  val.replace("abc")
end

str = "123"
replace(str)
puts str
```

outputs "abc".

Comment: it's still a reference to the object being passed in. If I change it to `val += " abc"` in the first call, it doesn't change it. It seems like they should behave the same. I don't think it's the 'newness' but rather the assignment operator changes the behavior.

Comment: Yes, like I said, the assignment reassigns the local `val` variable to something else.

Comment: “it's still a reference to the object being passed in”—nope. It’s a local variable. I have no idea why do you think they should behave the same, in _all_ the languages that allow pass-by-reference they behave that way.